# compare a list to a set efficiently

Tags: python, list, set, compare

Is there a more efficient way to make sure that a `list` contains all and only the elements of a `set` other then constructing another `set` from the `list`?

E.g. something that avoids copying and sorting the list a la

```
s = set([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ])
l = [ 1, 2, 3, 5 ]
if s!=set(l):
    print "bad list"
```

Comment: so i assum l can have duplicates. If you really care about not creating a new object then just iterate over the list and invalidate it if any element is not in the set. set `__contains__` is fast, but probably no faster than a new set

Comment: i mean, this is pretty efficient. sets are great for comparison. Unless the space is really critical, your gains will be negligible at best. So, is the space really that important?

Comment: @modesitt I may want to allow duplicates. @Paritosh Well, like I said, I'm looking for a way that avoids the copying and sorting that would be done by the `set` constructor. Consider this a theoretical question with these requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid constructing another set from the list by calling the `symmetric_difference` method of the set with the list:

```
if s.symmetric_difference(l):
    print "bad list"
```

Comment: Does this really not make a new set? It [seems to](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c)  from a glance on line 1716. You're being sneaky sneaky ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to allow duplicates, you would need some kind of extra space to keep track of things. The choice now however, can be simplified to either repeating the space for the list, or for the set. Incase the list is bigger than the set usually, the first function can save on some space. But caution: it would take more space incase the set is bigger than the list.

```
s = set([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ])
l = [ 1, 2, 3, 5 ]
```

Approach 1: creates a Counter in order of the set

```
def low_space_compare(some_set, some_list):        
    from collections import Counter
    state = Counter(some_set)    
    for item in some_list:
        if item not in state:
            print("bad")
            return "bad"
        state[item] -= 1
    if any(val > 0 for val in state.values()): #change to val != 0 if duplicates not allowed
        print("bad")
        return "bad"
    return "good"
```

On the other hand, if dupes were not allowed either, you could simply iterate through the list and remove from the set, requiring no extra space at all. But it mutates the set!!!

Approach 2: no extra space, cannot handle dupes

```
def low_space_compare_no_dupes(some_set, some_list):
    #need to create a copy of some_set if you (hopefully) take offense to mutating the original set
    for item in some_list:
        if item not in some_set:
            print("bad")
            return "bad"
        else:
            some_set.remove(item) #this makes a dupe value fail when you see it again
    if some_set:
        print("bad, set had extra stuff")
        return "bad"
    return "good"

low_space_compare(s, l) #bad
low_space_compare_no_dupes(s, l) #bad
print(s) #{4} uh oh.
```

Edit: Approach 3: worst case same as creating a new set from list n in the case where its a valid match, but short circuits:

```
def low_space_compare_no_counters(some_set, some_list):
    new_set = set()
    #need to create a copy of some_set if you (hopefully) take offense to mutating the original set
    for item in some_list:
        if item not in some_set:
            if item not in new_set:
                print("bad")
                return "bad"
            else:
                pass #ah, a dupe, keep going           
        else:
            some_set.remove(item)
            new_set.add(item)

    if some_set:
        print("bad, set had extra stuff")
        return "bad"
    return "good"

low_space_compare_no_counters(s, l)
```